# Don't refresh filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, refresh

I have an app that have a form with a selector and other fields (inputs), I am developing it with spring-mvc (jsp, javascript) and I have a problem when the selector changes of state (value) I have to change the value of others fields. To the jsp page I pass it a list into ModelMap and after I have to check that the selector changes to go checking this value with its list value because is here where the values of the other fields are. some idea?

my code:

My controller

```
    ...
        @RequestMapping(value = "/addDevice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String addShowDevice (ModelMap model, HttpSession session) throws Instantiation

Exception, IllegalAccessException
        {
            logger.info ("Entrando en add Device");
            ...

            DeviceObjects deviceObjects = new DeviceObjects ();

            //Only the admin can change all properties
            if(!profile.equals("admin")){
                model.addAttribute("hardwareDeviceTypeList", hardwareDeviceTypeBo.findAll());
            }
            model.addAttribute ("device", deviceObjects);
            return "addDevice";
        }
...
```

My jsp file

hardwareDeviceTypeList list include in the modelMap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#model").on('change',function(){
        var valor = $(this).val();
        for(ind=0; ind<hardwareDeviceTypeList.length; ind++)
        {
            if (hardwareDeviceTypeList[ind].model == model){
                document.getElementById("maker").value = hardwareDeviceTypeList[ind].maker;
                document.getElementById("manufacturer").value = hardwareDeviceTypeList[ind].manufacturer;
                document.getElementById("vendor").value = hardwareDeviceTypeList[ind].vendor;
                document.getElementById("name").value = hardwareDeviceTypeList[ind].name;
                break;
            }
        }
        alert(valor);
        alert(deviceObjects.deviceObjects.length);
    });
...
});
</script>
....
            <td>
                <fmt:message key="common.model"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="model" >
                        <form:option value=""><fmt:message key="element.select"/></form:option>
                        <form:options items="${listModel}" />
                </form:select>
          ...
          <form:input type="text" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" readonly="readonly" size="12" path="manufacturer" />
          ...
          <form:input path="name"/>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make it not refresh, or saying that it's a problem that it's not refreshing?

Comment: I want to say that the selector changes of value, the rest fields don´t change. Don´t refresh the fields

Comment: Yes but are you saying that this is what it DOES (and you don't want it to), or what you WANT it to do (and, at the moment, it doesn't do that)?

Comment: what you want it to do (and, at the moment, it doesn't do that)

Comment: Okay, so at the moment, what does it do when the user selects a value? It refreshes the other fields?

Comment: Yes, I know like refresh them, I make it with javascript, I don´t know like send the data of the jsp (data are sent from controller (spring-mvc) to jsp file) to this function javascript. This data are list of Object